# Easiest way to implement hreflang tag for multilingual site

Tags: joomla, hreflang

I have been asked to implement the hreflang tags for an existing site having following structure and tons of pages.

1. www.abc.com (main site in English)
2. zh.abc.com (site in
   Chinese)
3. jp.abc.com (site in Japanese)

Site has been built on Joomla 3.6.2. As there are too many pages in the site, it will not be feasible to edit each and every page to add the tags to the header therefore I want help in devising a simpler and robust approach to achieve the same.

Please feel free to ask if require further details.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Extensions > Plugins > System - Language Filter, and make sure it's published and that Add Alternate Meta Tags and  Add x-default Meta Tags are enabled. I also disabled the automatic language change, as I read elsewhere that the crawler may not pick up some of the languages if that's enabled.

Answer (score 0):

just one question regarding this issue. Should the sites on the subdomains have the same structure and the same URLs?

E. g.

abc.com/about_us.html
de.abc.com/about_us.html
ru.abc.com/about_us.html

or is it possible to use different URLs?

E. g.

abc.com/about_us.html
de.abc.com/ueber_uns.html
ru.abc.com/o_nas.html